# I don't understand the error and can someone please help?

Tags: errors

[image]

I have done this, but I don't understand what does the line runaway argument? and file ended while scanning use. Now it doesn't allow me to get the pdf version and I'm terribly stuck. Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Looks like you have an empty line / `\par` in a figure caption or a closing brace `}` is missing. But it’s quite hard to help without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and the code only on a small screenshot …

Comment: Anyway :-) Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all aux, toc, lot and lof files? And tried to compile again? Many editors have a button for hvis type of clean up.

Comment: @Johannes_B sorry list of figures not table of contents (original comment deleted)

Comment: Please, provide minimal working example (not snippet of your editor), which gives this error. You can obtain it with cutting your original file so long that error dismiss. From your picture also follows that `\author{...` is not closed. You probably have more errors in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have used `\label{fig:example}` multiple times which accounts for the first set of warnings. Each label is supposed to be unique in the document.

the runaway argument error is most like use of a fragile command in the caption for the figure with caption 3 x 3 grids...

you need to use `\protect` in front of fragile commands if used in a caption. note the `.lof` file that stores the list of figures information obtained from the captions will be corrupt so you need to delete that after fixing the caption, so that a new version can be written.

David